# Oracle PL/SQL ORA-00937 "not a single-group group function"

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

Im working with the oracle pdf's to learn pl/sql.
There is an exercise where i have to create a new table with data out
of two other tables already existing. I thought this would do the trick:

```
CREATE TABLE new_depts 
AS SELECT d.department_id, d.department_name, sum(e.salary) dept_sal 
FROM employees e, departments d 
WHERE e.department_id = d.department_id;
```

But this raises the following error:

```
SQL-Fehler: ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
00937. 00000 -  "not a single-group group function"
```

I cant find something usefull about this error. From what i know yet
about SQL my code should work fine!

Am i wrong?

Comment: If you just started learning SQL, then you should stop using implicit joins in the `WHERE` clause and use an explicit `JOIN` operator. You also need to read up on the `GROUP BY` operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding group by clause :

```
CREATE TABLE new_depts 
AS SELECT d.department_id, d.department_name, sum(e.salary) dept_sal 
FROM employees e, departments d 
WHERE e.department_id = d.department_id
group by d.department_id,d.department_name
```

**Update 1**

You need to use group by clause in your select query because you are using `aggregate function: sum(e.salary)`. If you are using aggregate function then you need to have `group by` clause. Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/group-by/info) for more information about group by clause.

Answer (score 1):

The main concept to understanding why aggregate functions or columns that are specified in the GROUP BY clause cannot be mixed with other non aggregate expressions in the select list is the level of detail of the value they produce. The select list of the SELECT statement can include only expressions that produce values that are on the same level of detail as others in that select list.

Example 1: incorrect

```
SELECT avg(col1) --> level of detail of the value is aggregated 
      ,col2      --> level of detail of the value is only for one row
FROM table_a;
```

Example 2: correct

```
SELECT avg(col1) --> level of detail of the value is aggregated
      ,col2      --> level of detail of the value is aggregated
FROM table_a
GROUP BY col2;
```

By including a column in the GROUP BY clause you aggregate the specified column and change its level of detail from single row to aggregate.